# New line code is not working

Tags: css, newline

I would like to insert a new line between h2 and h3 without using "br"; I would like to use CSS. I find the "display: block;"as an answer many times on stack overflow, but it is not working for me. Any suggestions as to why it isn't working are greatly appreciated. This is my
My HTML:

```
<div id="content">
             <h2 class="hdr2"><b>Yoga-Meditation Benefits</b></h2>
…
```

My CSS:

```
h2.hdr2 {
            position:fixed;
            display: block;
              top: 180px;
              text-align: center;
            color:orange;

}
```

Comment: I don’t see any `h3` in the code, or any attempt at inserting a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are going for?

HTML:

```
    <div id="content">
             <h2 class="hdr2"><b>Yoga-Meditation Benefits</b></h2>
             <h2 class="hdr2"><b>Yoga-Meditation Benefits 2</b></h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  h2.hdr2 {
            position:relative;
              top: 180px;
              text-align: center;
            color:orange;

}
#content{
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/53rAk/1

Comment: Wow! I get it. The code worked. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's beceause of the `position` of your `h2`
If you want to fix the position of an element from the top, you should apply the property on the `#content`.
Try this :

```
#content {
            position:fixed;
            top: 180px;
}
h2.hdr2 {
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            color:orange;

}
```

If it still doesn't work, you can try to add the property : `clear:both;` on your h3.

Comment: Thanks. position: fixed moved the  paragraph up and did not insert a new line. clear:both didn't do anything.

Comment: I understand Maxime. I made a typo. Thank you